# Homebrew does not completely uninstall nginx

Tags: macos, homebrew, nginx

I installed yesterday nginx on my machine using

```
brew install nginx
```

Today I would like to remove the software, therefore I tried

```
brew uninstall nginx
```

which has been correctely executed. In fact if I ask again to uninstall nginx I get

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/nginx
```

The problem is that the files under

```
/usr/local/etc/nginx
```

has not been removed.

What is the correct way to remove them?
Thank you

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can just delete the directory `/usr/local/etc/nginx` and `/usr/local/var/www`.

Comment: thanks, my only concern is that /usr/local/etc/nginx seems to be under git version control :/

Comment: Not sure if you found your solution, but I just went through the same issue yesterday. I deleted the directories like @slhck suggested.

Comment: If `nginx` is installed with homebrew, than you also have to remove it from    
`/usr/local/var/run/nginx/` and nothing bad will happen

Answer (score 10):

As usual, use

```
rm -f -R /usr/local/nginx
rm -f /usr/local/sbin/nginx
```

Answer (score 6):

from terminal,

1. uninstall nginx using: `brew remove nginx`
2. remove nginx config files using:  `rm -r /usr/local/var/run/nginx`

Answer (score 4):

November 2017 – El Capitan

It seems the answers are outdated. 
After trying a lot of options, I've finally found the right instructions:

remove from brew:

```
brew remove nginx
```

remove config:

The folder was changing; make sure the folder exists. 
If it does not exist, it's because brew could change for the future versions (I hope not). 
In this case, tell me to update my answer.

```
rm -f -R /usr/local/etc/nginx
```

Comment: Hi dave, I'm a bit surprised you didn't update or edit the other answer which stated the same solution, save for the location of the config ...

Comment: you can downvote if you don't like

Answer (score 2):

I found an nginx directory in all these places mentioned above. 
This is a succinct list of all the commands above:

```
brew remove nginx
rm -f -R /usr/local/nginx
rm -f /usr/local/sbin/nginx
rm -r /usr/local/var/run/nginx
rm -f -R /usr/local/etc/nginx  
rm -r /usr/local/opt/nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but nginx was installed in `/usr/local/opt/`.  To resolve I did:

```
rm -r /usr/local/opt/nginx
```